# Opposite of "titular"?

Tags: adjectives, antonyms

This is something that's been bothering me. **Titular** is an adjective which identifies an object as the source of the subject's name. According to Google:

> Titular: denoting a person or thing from whom or which the name of an artistic work or similar is taken.

It can be used in a sentence like, "*Ivanhoe* follows the adventures of the titular hero" or "*Hey Hey We're the Monkees* was written by the titular band". But how do you express the opposite relation, where the noun takes its name from the subject rather than gives its name to it? As in, "The adventures of Sir Wilfred of Ivanhoe are detailed in the ______ book, *Ivanhoe*" or "*The Monkees* wrote the ____ song"?

Eponymous doesn't seem to work, as it denotes the same relationship as titular. You could use "the book/song of the same name", but that would only really work if the source and the work had exactly the same name. It also doesn't really express the subject as the source of the name. I've looked for antonyms, but most online dictionaries only give antonyms like "real" or "actual".

Is there a word or phrase that works like this?

Comment: Rather than an *opposite*, I believe you seek the *complement*.

Comment: @Octopus That's probably a more appropriate term for it. Although I don't know what the actual opposite of titular would entail. Something from which the name of a work isn't taken?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Eponymous* does work in your blanks. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eponymous) gives two definitions for *eponymous*:

1. (of a person) giving their name to something.
2. (of a thing) named after a particular person.

The second sense works for you, since the book and the song are things named after a particular person (or band).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the word could be used to show both relations. Eponymous it is then!

Answer (score 6):

I don't see what's wrong with "eponymous"

[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eponymous) even use a similar example to yours.

> Eponymous, adjective
>
> 1) (of a person) being the person after whom a literary work, film,
>   etc, is named   ⇒ "the eponymous heroine in the film of Jane Eyre"
>
> 2)(of a literary work, film, etc) named after its central 
>      character or creator   ⇒ "the Stooges' eponymous debut album"

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that eponymous could work like that!